# Why won't any water squares spawn in on my netlogo simulation?

Tags: netlogo

```
globals [grass]
;; Sheep and wolves are both breeds of turtle.
breed [sheep a-sheep]  ;; sheep is its own plural, so we use "a-sheep" as the singular.
breed [wolves wolf]
turtles-own [energy]       ;; both wolves and sheep have energy
patches-own [countdown]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [ set pcolor green ]
  ;; check GRASS? switch.
  ;; if it is true, then grass grows and the sheep eat it
  ;; if it false, then the sheep don't need to eat
  if water? [
    if grass? [
    ask patches [
      set pcolor one-of [green brown blue]
      if-else pcolor =[green blue]
        [ set countdown grass-regrowth-time ]
        [ set countdown random grass-regrowth-time ] ;; initialize grass grow clocks randomly for brown patches
    ]
    ]
    if grass? [
      ask patches [
        set pcolor one-of [green brown]
      if-else pcolor = green
        [ set countdown grass-regrowth-time ]
        [ set countdown random grass-regrowth-time ] ;; initialize grass grow clocks randomly for brown patches
    ]
  ]
  ]
  set-default-shape sheep "sheep"
  create-sheep initial-number-sheep  ;; create the sheep, then initialize their variables
  [
    set color white
    set size 1.5  ;; easier to see
    set label-color blue - 2
    set energy random (2 * sheep-gain-from-food)
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  set-default-shape wolves "wolf"
  create-wolves initial-number-wolves  ;; create the wolves, then initialize their variables
  [
    set color black
    set size 2  ;; easier to see
    set energy random (2 * wolf-gain-from-food)
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  display-labels
  set grass count patches with [pcolor = green]
  ;;set water count patches with [pcolor = blue]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if not any? turtles [ stop ]
  ask sheep [
    move
    if water? [
      if pcolor = blue [
        set energy energy = 0
        death ;;sheep drowns
      ]
    ]
    if grass? [
      set energy energy - 1  ;; deduct energy for sheep only if grass? switch is on
      eat-grass
    ]
    death
    reproduce-sheep
  ]
  ask wolves [
    move
    if water? [
      if pcolor = blue [
        set energy energy = 0
        death
    ]
  ]
    set energy energy - 1  ;; wolves lose energy as they move
    catch-sheep
    death
    reproduce-wolves
  ]
  if grass? [ ask patches [ grow-grass ] ]
  set grass count patches with [pcolor = green]
  tick
  display-labels
end

to move  ;; turtle procedure
  rt random 50
  lt random 50
  fd 1
end

to eat-grass  ;; sheep procedure
  ;; sheep eat grass, turn the patch brown
  if pcolor = green [
    set pcolor brown
    set energy energy + sheep-gain-from-food  ;; sheep gain energy by eating
  ]
end

to reproduce-sheep  ;; sheep procedure
  if random-float 100 < sheep-reproduce [  ;; throw "dice" to see if you will reproduce
    set energy (energy / 2)                ;; divide energy between parent and offspring
    hatch 1 [ rt random-float 360 fd 1 ]   ;; hatch an offspring and move it forward 1 step
  ]
end

to reproduce-wolves  ;; wolf procedure
  if random-float 100 < wolf-reproduce [  ;; throw "dice" to see if you will reproduce
    set energy (energy / 2)               ;; divide energy between parent and offspring
    hatch 1 [ rt random-float 360 fd 1 ]  ;; hatch an offspring and move it forward 1 step
  ]
end

to catch-sheep  ;; wolf procedure
  let prey one-of sheep-here                    ;; grab a random sheep
  if prey != nobody                             ;; did we get one?  if so,
    [ ask prey [ die ]                          ;; kill it
      set energy energy + wolf-gain-from-food ] ;; get energy from eating
end

to death  ;; turtle procedure
  ;; when energy dips below zero, die
  if energy < 0 [ die ]
end

to grow-grass  ;; patch procedure
  ;; countdown on brown patches: if reach 0, grow some grass
  if pcolor = brown [
    ifelse countdown <= 0
      [ set pcolor green
        set countdown grass-regrowth-time ]
      [ set countdown countdown - 1 ]
  ]
end

to display-labels
  ask turtles [ set label "" ]
  if show-energy? [
    ask wolves [ set label round energy ]
    if grass? [ ask sheep [ set label round energy ] ]
  ]
end
```

but when I run this ( you have to place a on off switch for water? in the wolf sheep predation) it runs as if I made no changes at all. Why  is this? How can I fix this?

anything related to water was added to the code by me.

Comment: i seriously do not understand this or really the language much in general, but my problems are surrounding the part where it asks grass if it's on after asking water... i think... but this is a big problem...

Answer (score 1):

You have two if statements inside the first `if water?` (in `setup`), and both respond to `grass?` So you do turn some patches blue, but then you execute the send `if` and turn all either brown or green.

Whenever you get confused, make smaller procedures.  E.g.,

```
to color-patches
  if grass? [
    let patch-colors [green brown]
    if water? [set patch-colors [green brown blue]]
    ask patches [set pcolor one-of patch-colors]
  ]
end
```

One other problem, is that you don't want `if pcolor = [green blue]`, which (i) will always be false and (ii) is trying to set a regrowth countdown on water patches.

Comment: Perhaps by `pcolor = [green blue]` you mean `pcolor = green or pcolor = blue`, or equivalently `member? pcolor [green blue]`? Not sure.

Comment: @SethTisue I'm guessing your comment was meant for the question rather than for the answer.